# why does html parser stop when meet script tag

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I heard that javascript can manipulate dom.
That's why parser stop when meet script tag.
But I cannot understand.
I want to know some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with manipulating the DOM.

JavaScript can write to the document:

```
<h1>Example</h1>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<p>Fin</p>
```

with

```
 document.write('foo');
```

The HTML parser has to stop while the script is downloaded and executed in case it has something like that `document.write` statement. It has to parse `foo` into a text node before it reaches the `<p>` start tag.

Note that if you aren't writing parser blocking JS, you can use the [`defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Comment: Does it mean that if I use the document.write(), parser have to stop parsing and run the script to prevent inefficiency?

Comment: No. It means that if you use a non-defered script the parser has to stop parsing and run the script so it knows if the script outputs any content it needs to parse before continuing with the HTML in the source document.

Comment: I found [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work#preload_scanner) on MDN. And It says "Waiting to obtain CSS doesn't block HTML parsing or downloading, but it does block JavaScript, **because JavaScript is often used to query CSS properties' impact on elements.**" What does it mean ? 'query CSS Properties's imact on elements'??